# Unable to load Json data in MG data table

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I'm new to D3.js.
I created a script but I can't load any json data into my table.

```
d3.json('C:\Software\Data\dirk\development\D3_TestLab\data\StatusTabel.json', function (data) {

    var table_data = data

    var table1 = MG.data_table({
        data: table_data,
        //title: '',
        //description: 'A table has many of the same properties as any other data graphic.',
        show_tooltips: true
    })

        .target('#div1')

        .number({ accessor: 'BU', label: 'BU', width: 120, font_size: 14, layout: 'center' })
        .number({ accessor: 'Lines', label: '# Lines', width: 190, font_size: 14, layout: 'center' })
      //.number({accessor: 'Errors', label: 'Errors', width: 170, font_size: 14, color: function(d){ return d > 0 ? '#f70101' : 'auto'; })
        .number({ accessor: 'Errors', label: 'Errors', width: 190, font_size: 14, color: 'red', allign: 'center' })
        .number({ accessor: 'Shift', label: 'Shift', width: 270, font_size: 14 })

        .display();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked your logic, but few of the points I can suggest here are,

1) Try changing url to json file from:
'C:\Software\Data\dirk\development\D3_TestLab\data\StatusTabel.json'
to:
'file:///C:/Software/Data/dirk/development/D3_TestLab/data/StatusTabel.json'

2) The function(data) should have another parameter error. i.e. function(error, data) { ... }

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, the function should have two params `function(error, data)`. Also to debug if you are even receiving the JSON file, try adding a `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` right after reading in the JSON. This way you can see if the call is working.